# Elementor Pro Error. wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/license/api.php:174 ElementorPro\License\API::is_request_running()

Tags: php, elementor

`wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/license/api.php:174 ElementorPro\License\API::is_request_running()`

`wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/license/api.php:205 ElementorPro\License\API::get_license_data()`

`wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/license/admin.php:224 ElementorPro\License\Admin->display_page()`

`wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 do_action('elementor_page_elementor-license') wp-admin/admin.php:259`

Please help me how would i fix this error

i am sure it is not plugin conffilicton error, i already tried by doing all theme and plugin diactivate and activate

Comment: Provide more details about the error. What were you trying to do? When did you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, I got it solved from database, in phpmyadmin go to _option then in that search _elementor_pro_api_requests_lock this, and remove its value in the option_value field. Hope it works

Comment: Or delete the whole option and see if it helps, also make sure have a backup so you can restore